# IE9 CSS hack doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to apply some css properties for IE9 only
here is my css code:

```
:root ul li.open,
:root ul li.closed {
    list-style-position: outside \0/IE9;
    float:right \0/IE9;
    width:calc(100% - 20px) \0/IE9;

}
```

also, I tried to do it, like this:

```
:root ul li.open,
:root ul li.closed {
    list-style-position: outside\;
    float:right\;
    width:calc(100% - 20px)\;

}
```

and like this:

```
ul li.open,
ul li.closed {
    list-style-position: outside\9\0;
    float:right\9\0;
    width:calc(100% - 20px)\9\0;
}
```

what I missing?

Comment: Can you upload your example code in snippet

Comment: ...also, what **specifically** isn't working.

Comment: CSS hacks are evil. To address IE9 and below, use something saner, like IE conditional comments.